# I want MPLAB to reset and continue running after a software RESET instruction in debug mode

Tags: debugging, reset, pic, microchip, mplab

When running Release code, when the MicroChip PIC code program executes a RESET instructions, the processor is reset, it is in a well defined state, and execution starts from the beginning.

When running in the Debug mode, MPLAB halts completely; I must manually command it to run again. I want it instead to behave the same as the Release mode: reset and start execution from the beginning.

I tried replacing the RESET instruction with a GOTO 0, instruction, but the PIC processor is in a weird state when I do that, and the CAN2 port doesn't work (CAN1 works fine). Only a true hardware reset will restore normal operation.

I am using MPLAB 8.2, and the target has a PIC30F IC.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to declare a routine as follows, called whenever I want a software reset. The NOP has a breakpoint placed on it, so when `vReset()` is called, the debugger halts, and I can use MPLABX's reset function (Debug|Reset) to restart the processor myself. The routine executes normally for a release build.

```
  void vReset(void)
  // This routine resets the CPU
  {
     // Perform any other cleanup tasks before resetting...

     // If in debug mode, hang here before the reset (a reset locks up the debugger)
     #ifdef __DEBUG  // Defined by MPLABX when building project for debugging
        for(;;)
        {
           __asm__ volatile ("nop");  // In case a breakpoint is placed here, will not get optimized away
        };
     #endif

     // Reset CPU
     __asm__ volatile ("reset");
  }
```

I do not use MPLAB8, so perhaps you need to test for something other than `__DEBUG`, and if you are using older compilers (e.g. C30), the asm construct might be formatted differently.

Comment: Thanks, only tangentially related to my question. Would you be able to suggest how I could have phrased my question better, so as not to cause such misunderstanding?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to achieve what you are asking.In my experience with MPLABX, a software reset also resets debugging mode, necessitating a complete restart of debugging environment (which involves reprogramming the PIC, so it's slow). It seems that something similar happens under MPLAB8. My workaround is not ideal (still requiring a manual restart), but at least I get an automatic "trap" of software resets under debugging mode, so a debugging session can survive a software reset.

Comment: > To my knowledge, there is no way to achieve what you are asking.
   
 
Dang! Thanks.